# Python: Función comienza a fallar sin razón aparente

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Este programa es para la inscripcion de estudiantes en un hipotetico curso.
Esta función ya la habia usado anteriormente y funcionaba, no sé que ocurre ahora q no hace como deberia. Al final debe colocarme en un arreglo las materias equivalentes al id de las mismas:

```
materias = [['Matématica', 0], ['Química', 1], ['Física', 2], ['Historia', 3], ['Geografía', 4], ['Idiomas', 5], ['Biología', 6], ['Lógica', 7], ['Ed.Física', 8], ['Civico', 9]]
```

Este es un posible resultado correcto que DEBERIA dar:

```
['Geografía', 'Matématica', 'Historia']
```

Pero da cosas como está:

```
['Geografía', 'Matématica', 'Historia', 'Geografía']
```

E incluso:

```
['Geografía', 'Matématica', 'Geografía', 'Matématica']
```

La siguiente funcion llama a todas las demas del modulo:

```
    def inscribir_materias():
        
        inscritas = []
        asignatura = -1
        centinela = 1
        materias_alumno = []
        k=0
        while True:
            print("""
                    1- Inscribir materia
                    0- Salir del sistema
                """)
            try:
                    centinela = int(input("Opción: "))
            except:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Favor introduzca una opcion valida")
    
            if centinela in [0, 1]:
                if centinela == 1:
                    break
                
                elif centinela == 0: 
                    os.sys.exit()
                
                    
            else: 
                os.system("cls")
                print("Favor introduzca una opcion valida")  
    
        while centinela == True:
            
            asignatura = menu_materias(inscritas)
    
            if asignatura not in inscritas and asignatura is not None and asignatura != 10:
                inscritas.append(asignatura)
            else:
                asignatura = menu_materias(inscritas)
            os.system("cls")
            print(inscritas)
            menu_main()
            
            centinela = int(input("Opción: "))
            if centinela == 0:
                    break #Se rompe el bucle y termina el programa
            elif centinela == 1:
                    materias_alumno = materias_inscritas(inscritas)#Procesar el arreglo inscritas
                    #Esta funcion materias inscritas, es la q cambia los id q uno ingresa por el menu en los nombres equivalentes de las materias.
            
        return materias_alumno
```

La funcion a continuacion es materias_inscritas, y debe devolver un arreglo de solo tres elementos como maximo.

```
    def materias_inscritas(inscritas):
        """[Identificar nombre del  materia a partir de su id]
    
        Args:
            inscritas ([lista]): [Lista con los id de las materias inscritas, debe venir completo con todas las materias]
    
        Returns:
            [lista]: [Arreglo con la sublista con el nombre de la materia correspondiente y su id]
        """
        k=0
        arreglo_materias = []
        print("materias longitud", len(materias))
        
        for i in materias:
            if len(arreglo_materias) > 2:
                    break
            for j in range(0,10):
                if materias[j][1] in inscritas:
                    arreglo_materias.append(materias[j][0])
                       
                else:
                    pass 
        k+=1
        return arreglo_materias
```

El detalle es que antes esto funcionaba bien y me devolvia lo que pedia, pero cuando lo llamé desde el main.py. lo que recibia era un arreglo extraño, q tenia a veces una materia repetida, e incluso a veces borraba una de las 3 materias ingresadas y la sustituia por una dublicada. Luego intenté llamar las mismas funciones desde el modulo donde estan y tambien me dieron error, cosa que ANTES NO PASABA.
Alguien sabe q ocurre con el interprete???

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que parece, estás haciendo un doble bucle innecesario:

```py
for i in materias:
    if len(arreglo_materias) > 2:
        break
    for j in range(0,10):
        if materias[j][1] in inscritas:
            arreglo_materias.append(materias[j][0])
        else:
            pass
```

Recorres dos veces la lista de materias. Gracias a que pones un `break`, el bucle se corta y no añade dos veces todas y cada una de las materias inscritas.

Debería ser un sólo bucle:

```py
for materia in materias:
    if len(arreglo_materias) > 2:
        break
    if materia[1] in inscritas:
        arreglo_materias.append(materia[0])
    else:
        pass
```

Aprovechando las facilidades de python, aún se puede hacer más compacto:

```py
arreglo_materias = [materia[0] for materia in materias if materia[1] in inscritas]
```

Si quieres limitar a 3 materias máximo, cambia `inscritas` por `inscritas[:3]`:

```py
arreglo_materias = [materia[0] for materia in materias if materia[1] in inscritas[:3]]
```

Comment: Me da el mismo error. Lo extraño es q el error q digo, solo se da cuando en el menu de opciones, elijo salir inmediatamente despues de haber ingresado las 3 materias. Por el contrario si intento inscribir una mas aunque tenga las tres, no me lo permite, pero cuando justo despues de darle a esa opcion le doy a salir, aparecen las tres materias correctamente.

Comment: Faltaría ver el código de `menu_materias` para poder hacer una prueba. Añádelo a la pregunta.